# show that $ \ g \ $ is uniformly continuous on $ \ [a,b] \ $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ \ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \ $ be a Riemann integrable function . Define $ \ g(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(s)ds \ $ , where $ \  x\in [a,b] \ $.

Show that there is a constant $ \ K \ $ such that $$ \ |g(x)-g(y)|<K|x-y| \ \ \ \ \forall \ x,y \in [a,b]$$

Hence show that $ \ g \ $ is uniformly continuous on $ \ [a,b] \ $

**Answer:**

I have already shown that $$  |g(x)-g(y)|<K|x-y| \ \ \ \ \forall \ x,y \in [a,b]$$

**How to show that** $ \ \ g \ $ is uniformly continuous on $ \ [a,b] \ $?

I think $ g(x)=\int_a^x f(s)ds \ $ is monotonic and so

$$ g(x)-g(y)<K(x-y) \ $$
which can be written as $$ g(x)-g(y) \leq K(x-y) $$
So uniformly continuos.

**Am I right?**

Comment: What if $f(x)$ is both positive and negative in $[a,b]$?  Then $g(x)$ won't be monotone.

Comment: nothing mentioned about the sign of $ \ f(x) \ $. Ok then any other way?

Comment: [Lipschitz Condition implies Uniform Continuity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lipschitz_Condition_implies_Uniform_Continuity)

Comment: But  how $ \ |g(x)-g(y)|<K |x-y| \ $ implies  that $ \ g(x)-g(y)<K(x-y) \ $ ?

Comment: Your inequality is known as the "Lipschitz Condition". One can easily look up proofs that Lipschitz implies Uniform Continuity

Comment: And the proof can be summarized as "take $\delta = \varepsilon/K$"

Comment: Why do you want to remove absolute value signs when they are necessary for uniform continuity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \epsilon >0$ be given.

We need to find a $\delta$ such that $$|x-y|<\delta \implies |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon.$$
 Since we have 
$$|g(x)-g(y)|<K|x-y| \ \ \ \ \forall \ x,y \in [a,b]$$

Let $\delta= \epsilon /K.$

If $|x-y|<\delta $ then  $$|g(x)-g(y)|<K|x-y|<K\delta =\epsilon, \forall \ x,y \in [a,b]$$

Thus g is uniformly continuous on $[a,b].